# Java ResultSet rows populated by last row values

Tags: java, mysql, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am having a bizzar issue. I am reading database table and storing each column into resultset but the issue is, resultset populated with last row values only. For example, I have 10 rows I am getting 10 rows but values are replicated with last row values.

Actual Database rows (Example):

Id   Name  Address 
1   A     Address1
2   B     Address2
3  C     Address3
4   D     Address4
5   E     Address5

Getting out of resultset

5   E     Address5
5   E     Address5
5   E     Address5
5   E     Address5
5   E     Address5

My code as follow in class:

```
    public static ArrayList<Animal> getAllAnimals() throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement query = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    ArrayList<Animal> results = new ArrayList();
    try {

        // connect to database
        conn = Database.mySqlDBConn().getConnection();
        // run a query
        query = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM animal");
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String  animal_order = rs.getString("animal_order");
            String family = rs.getString("family");
            String  genus = rs.getString("genus");
            String  species = rs.getString("species");
            String zoo = rs.getString("zoo");
            int number_avilable= rs.getInt("number_avilable");
            System.out.print(name);
            Animal animal = new Animal(name,animal_order,family, genus, species, zoo, number_avilable);
            results.add(animal);
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(conn != null) conn.close();
    }
    return results;
}
```

I am calling:

```
@Path("/animal/")
public class ZooController {
/**
 *
 * @return
 * @throws Exception
 */
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)



     public Response title () throws Exception{

    //ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
    //animals.addAll(Animal.getAllAnimals());
    //(Animal.getAllAnimals());
    //System.out.println(animals);
    return Response.ok(Animal.getAllAnimals()).build();

}
```

FYI: This is a rest api using JAVA JERSEY MySQL I am using Netbeans

Comment: You haven't shown your `Animal` class -- are the class fields `static`?

Comment: @brso05 I am sure data not duplicated in database

Comment: @rgettman `public class Animal {
    private static String name;
    private static String  animal_order;
    private static String family;
    private static String  genus;
    private static String  species;
    private static String zoo;
    private static int number_avilable;
    
    } <more code>
    `

Comment: You have a `Animal` class and it has a static method `getAllAnimals())` and in this method you are trying to populate a `ArrayList` and this `ArrayList` is containing `Animal` objects. Don't you think the implementation approach is in correct?

Comment: Your variables in `Animal` class are `static` like @rgettman said...get rid of the `static` make them instance attributes and it should fix your problem.

Comment: Solved, it was the static variable issue. Thanks all